# Web API Null Navigation Property

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I am getting an error when I try to expand a navigation property of an object in my model.

```
eg. /odata/Products?$expand=ProductDetails
```

I get the following error:

```
No NavigationLink factory was found for the navigation property 'ProductDetails' from entity type 'ProductModels.Models.Product' on entity set 'Products'. Try calling HasNavigationPropertyLink on the EntitySetConfiguration.
```

Parameter name: navigationProperty

My model looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Name")]
    public PersonDetails PersonDetails { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDetails
{
    [Key]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

}
```

It is a one to zero/one relationship and you can see that my model is a bit odd in that PersonDetails is linked to Person by Person.Name = PersonDetails.FullName but Entity Framework 6 does handle it and generates the SQL like the following:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
N'f4243347-5b4c-4790-a07d-e8beb80bea72' AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
N'PersonDetails' AS [C2], 
N'f4243347-5b4c-4790-a07d-e8beb80bea72' AS [C3], 
[Extent2].[FullName] AS [FullName], 
[Extent2].[Age] AS [Age], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Name] IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C4]
FROM  [Persons] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [PersonDetails] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Name] = [Extent2].[FullName]
```

And in the results, many of the ProductDetails records are null, which is ok.

But it seems like the OData Formatter has a problem with it where Person.Name is null. I have the following set in my ProductsContext:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Product> Products { get; set;
```

And this ODataConventionModelBuilder:

```
builder.EntitySet<Vehicle>("Products");
```

I don't have a controller for ProductDetails because I don't want to access it directly, only through the Products controller.

If I add in a:

```
builder.EntitySet<Vehicle>("ProductDetails");
```

Then I get a:

```
The EDM instance of type '[ProductModels.Models.ProductDetails Nullable=True]' is missing the property 'FullName'.
```

Which makes sense because FullName may well be null on that ProductDetails record.

The only way forward I can see is to use HasNavigationPropertyLink instead of building the ProductDetails the standard way as above.

Can anyone give me any advice on what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

Add entry of Entity to `ODataConfig.cs` as following.

```
builder.EntitySet<EntityName>(typeof(EntityName).Name);
```

and the whole code will be like this

```
public static class ODataConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<EntityName>(typeof(EntityName).Name);
            var model = builder.GetEdmModel();
            config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", model);

            config.EnableQuerySupport();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code snippet:

```
   var products=builder.EntitySet<Vehicle>("Products");
   products.HasNavigationPropertiesLink(
                product.NavigationProperties,
                (entityContext, navigationProperty) =>
                {
                    object id;
                    entityContext.EdmObject.TryGetPropertyValue("ID", out id);
                    return new Uri(entityContext.Url.Link(ODataTestConstants.DefaultRouteName,
                new
                {
                    odataPath = entityContext.Url.CreateODataLink(
                        new EntitySetPathSegment(entityContext.NavigationSource.Name),
                        new KeyValuePathSegment(id.ToString()),
                        new NavigationPathSegment(navigationProperty))
                }));
                }, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. product doesn't seem to have a collection of NavigationProperties but product.EntityType does. Is this what I should use? Can I replace ODataTestConstants.DefaultRouteName with anything or does this need to refer to something? Can I use Url.ODataLink rather than Url.CreateODataLink? Can you tell me what entityContext.NavigationSource.Name should return - is there another library that I should reference?

Comment: Add some description about how the code works? and reply to comments? please.. :)

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
foreach (var navProp in products.EntityType.NavigationProperties)
            {
 products.HasNavigationPropertyLink(
           navprop,
           (entityContext, navigationProperty) =>
           {
               object id;
               entityContext.EdmObject.TryGetPropertyValue("ID", out id);
               return new Uri(entityContext.Url.CreateODataLink(
                     new EntitySetPathSegment(navprop.Name),
                     new KeyValuePathSegment(id.ToString())
                     ));
           }, false);
}
```

Comment: No description of what the code does? I tried using it - but there's no sign of EntitySetPathSegment/KeyValuePathSegment classes. Which version of OData is this?